# Emoji not visible when copied from one table to another in Mysql

Tags: mysql, collation, emoji

I have text with emojis in a sql table. Collation is set to utf8mb4_bin. The mobile app reads the emoji from table and displays correctly. It inserts the emojis properly.

Using dashboard, sometimes I copy this text to another table with same column and collation. But emoji from this table is not visible in mobile app. I see only ????????

Why so?

Comment: Where was "collation" set to that??

Comment: I set the collation while creating the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally cracked it. It was an issue with database connection of the dashboard from where I was copying data from one table to another. the connection encoding was set to utf8.  I changed it to utf8mb4.

This link was also helpful in figuring out things.
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Question Marks (regular ones, not black diamonds) (Se?or for Señor):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

More discussion:  [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)